# JSP Reference Books

Tags: jsp

There seems to be a dearth of fresh JSP reference books to purchase.  Most are from between 1999 and 2003, with almost nothing after that.  There are still lots of Java books, and while most of the syntax is easily swapped, I'd rather have a reference book specifically for the dynamic browser aspect.

Does anyone have recommendations?

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic browser aspect ? :(

Comment: I meant the JSP component to Java, specifically.  I'm very new to the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Head First Servlets and JSP](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-Servlets-JSP-Certified/dp/0596516681/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1317054656&sr=8-1) covers the topic very comprehensively and gently. The 2nd edition was published in 2008 and AFAIK there have been little or no changes to the JSP spec since then.

Although this book covers both Servlets and JSPs, in most environments where JSPs are being used, Servlets (or something similar like Struts actions) are also used. Because JSPs *are* Servlets at runtime, it could be argued that understanding Servlets is a pre-requisite for understanding JSPs.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Head First Servlets and JSP by kathy Sierra & Bert Bates](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005405.do)
2. Java for the Web with Servlets, JSP, and EJB: A Developer's Guide to J2EE Solutions by Budi Kurniawan, this is a very old book most probably not available in market but I found it very interesting.

Though these are not particularly for JSP but I am sure you will get everything you're looking for.

The first one is undisputedly the best book available.I have the pdf of second one,in case you want to have a look.

Enjoy :)